# How do I access additional data from Azure Active Directory from my ASP.NET Core application?

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core, azure-active-directory

I have utilised our company active directory from our Azure platform in my ASP.NET Core Application.  I set this up as my authentication model when I first created my project.  There is a need for me to access additional details of users other than just their email address or name, for example, their `country`, `department` and `usage location`.  I'm not sure how you do this and was wondering if anyone could help.

The default setup of Azure AD Authentication doesn't include any models or account pages, it simply adds the app registration info to your `appsettings.json` and adds login partial view that uses identity:

```
@using System.Security.Principal

<ul class="navbar-nav">
@if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
{
        <li class="nav-item">
            <span class="nav-text text-dark">Hello @User.Identity.Name!</span>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="AzureAD" asp-controller="Account" asp-action="SignOut">Sign out</a>
        </li>
}
else
{
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="AzureAD" asp-controller="Account" asp-action="SignIn">Sign in</a>
        </li>
}
</ul>
```

Is there any way for me to expand this to grab the above-mentioned fields or do I need to create something new? tia.

Comment: Have you tried using Azure AD APIs?

Answer (score 0):

It should be in the **Claims** of the principal.

Put a breakpoint in one of your controllers or views. In your watch window, you may be able to cast the user to a ClaimsPrincipal and view the claims that come back from Azure AD.

See [Active Directory Claims Mapping](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-claims-mapping) for the claims list and mapping.

Also, ASP.Net Core 2.1 moved the AccountController and views into Razor Class libraries, so you won't see them in your usual directories save for the partial view. You can pull them back into your directories by using the scaffolding identity tool [here.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/scaffold-identity?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=visual-studio)

Answer (score 0):

By default only few of user properties are include in token and then map to your application's user claim principle . You can use [Microsoft Graph Api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) to retire user properties :

> Note: Getting a user returns a default set of properties only (businessPhones, displayName, givenName, id, jobTitle, mail, mobilePhone, officeLocation, preferredLanguage, surname, userPrincipalName). Use $select to get the other properties and relationships for the [user object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/user?view=graph-rest-1.0).

[Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth/?context=graph%2Fapi%2F1.0&view=graph-rest-1.0) is Microsoft Graph Auth document  and [here](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/aspnetcore-connect-sample) is code sample for ASP.NET Core .